# Key not valid for use in specified state CryptographicException with BouncyCastle

Tags: vb.net, security, exception, cryptography, itext

Been searching the web and blogs and finding scraps here and there, and trying to put them all together to be able to use `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` to digitally sign a PDF file with iTextSharp library.

I have a sign button with the following code behind it:

```
    Dim m As New PdfManipulation
    Dim store As New X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)

    Dim collection As X509Certificate2Collection = CType(store.Certificates, X509Certificate2Collection)
    Dim fcollection As X509Certificate2Collection = CType(collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, False), X509Certificate2Collection)
    Dim scollection As X509Certificate2Collection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Test Certificate Select", "Select a certificate from the following list to get information on that certificate", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)

    For Each x509 As X509Certificate2 In scollection
        m.DigitallySignPdf("C:\Users\my\Desktop\populates.pdf", "C:\Users\my\Desktop\A.pdf", "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].SignatureField1[0]", x509)
    Next x509

    store.Close()
```

The above code works, it opens up my cert store and I choose a certificate. It then passes the certificate to the following PdfManiuplation class for signing.

PdfManipulation Code:

```
Public Class PdfManipulation

Public Sub DigitallySignPdf(ByVal sourceDocument As String, _
                            ByVal destinationPath As String, _
                            ByVal fieldNameToSign As String, _
                            ByVal signature As X509Certificate2)

    Dim reader As New PdfReader(sourceDocument)
    Using fout As New FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Using stamper As PdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fout, ControlChars.NullChar)
            ' appearance
            Dim appearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance
            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(fieldNameToSign)

            ' digital signature
            Dim akp = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(signature.PrivateKey).Private
            Dim es As IExternalSignature = New PrivateKeySignature(akp, "SHA-256")
            Dim cp As New Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser()


            MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, es, New Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate() {cp.ReadCertificate(signature.RawData)}, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS)

            stamper.Close()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

End Class
```

When it gets to

```
Dim akp = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(signature.PrivateKey).Private
```

thats when the Exception is thrown. The certificate I choose is the same certificate I sign everything with on my machine, so I know it's good. Any help as to why this would be throwing this error would be greatly appreciated, or a pointer in the right direction.

Also here is my list of Imports:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.security
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
```

And have to add a reference to:

```
System.Security
```

StackTrace:

```
    System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146893813
  Message=Key not valid for use in specified state.

  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ExportKey(SafeKeyHandle hKey, Int32 blobType, Object cspObject)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(Boolean includePrivateParameters)
       at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(RSA rsa)
       at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKey)
       at AccessRequest.PdfManipulation.DigitallySignPdf(String sourceDocument, String destinationPath, String fieldNameToSign, X509Certificate2 signature) in C:\PdfManipulation.vb:line 237
       at Form.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Form.vb:line 251
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at app.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 11111.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Also after further testing and looking at the Private key through the IDE, I did notice

```
signature.privatekey.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable = False
```

would this possibly be the cause of the error and if so, how do make a selected certificate exportable? As the only thing I have seen through searching is actually creating a new certificate and setting the StorageFlag to Exportable and I am not trying to create a new certificate. I am just trying to use the  selected certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the amount of information you accumulated in your question, but please also include the stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was being caused by the fact that Private Certificate was **NOT** exportable.

I had been wondering through all my testing why I was not being prompted even once for my smart card pin for the certificate I was choosing. Which lead me to finally selecting one of my certificates that I know would not ask for pin, and viola, the pdf exported and was signed. Even stepped through the code to view the certificate privatekey property and this time it read

```
signature.privatekey.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable = True
```

Which finally matched another form i discovered, that stated they fixed their error by making the private key exportable. Now all I have to do is figure out how to make this work with certificates that should be asking me for my pin. If i ever discover that problem I will post back here.

Comment: I would like to know too

Answer (score 0):

You are right pointing out about the certificate not being exportable

So change:

> Dim akp =
> Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(signature.PrivateKey).Private

> Dim es As IExternalSignature = New PrivateKeySignature(akp, "SHA-256")

to just:

> Dim es As IExternalSignature = New
> security.X509Certificate2Signature(signature, "SHA-256")